# Datatables Jquery seperate search fields under every th

Tags: php, jquery, html, datatable

I´m trying to get search fields underneath the table headers in a datatable but it´s not working. Let alone the normal example where it´s in the footer doesn´t work for me either.

I have used this as an example:
https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

but it's not working for me for some reason. In the code of the example it says to create the tfoot with the exact data as the thead but it's just creating a new line with the same data for some reason.

The example html code:

```
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
```

I am using the exact same script code of the example with scroll added which is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#example').dataTable( {
    "scrollY": true
} );
// Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
$('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
    var title = $('#example thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
} );

// DataTable
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// Apply the search
table.columns().every( function () {
    var that = this;

    $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
        that
            .search( this.value )
            .draw();
    } );
} );
```

} );

My table looks like this:

```
<table id="example" class="display">
<thead>
<tr><th>
    //php generated code that shows header titles
</th></tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<th>
    //php generated code that shows header titles
</th>
</tr>

</tfoot>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
//php generated code that shows body data
</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

So my code basically has 2 rows of th's at the moment and no input fields at all in the table. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Please change code from

```
var title = $('#example thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
```

to

```
var title = $(this).text();
```

And you may be find input fields on tfoot.